# Is it bad practice or incorrect to store a method in a variable which will be used in an "if" condition?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, variables, methods

This is a generalized question that I had while working on a basic jquery contact form verification and I could not seem to find an answer for it.

### Here is an example of what I mean:

(the form action is set as such while this page is in development, later is changed to message service url)

```
    <form name="contact_form" action="#">
       <input id="name_field" name="name" type="text" required>
       <input id="email_field" name="email" type="email" inputmode="email" required pattern="^\b[\w\.-]+@{1}[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,6}\b">
       <textarea id="message_field" name="message" type="text" required>
       <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

### Below is a generalization of the Jquery I have been using.

```
 $(function(){
    var emailF = $('#email_field');
    var emailStr = emailF.val();
    var nameF = $('#name_field');
    var nameStr = nameF.val();
    var msgF = $('#message_field');
    var msgStr = msgF.val();
    var regex = new RegExp(/^\b[\w\.-]+@{1}[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,6}\b/i);

    function blankCheck(){
    
    // BELOW line is where the issue happens
       if (nameStr != "" && emailStr != "" && msgStr != ""){
          alert ('blankCheck PASS!!!');
          return true;
       } else {
          alert ('blankCheck FAIL!!!');
          return false;
       };
    });


    $('#submit').on('submit',function(e){
       function validateAll(){
          if ( blankCheck() && regex.test(emailStr) ){
             alert('validateAll PASS!!!');
             $('#submit').val("SENDING...");
      // This is followed by many setTimeout functions that animate elements on current page
          } else {
             $('#submit').css({'background-color':'red'});
             alert('validateAll FAIL!!!');
      // Wanted to include some UX negative feedback animation on button, but browser validation (from HTML) prevents it from executing (other than ui:error type pseudoclasses)
          };
       });

       validateAll();

       $.when(validateAll).done(function(){
           e.preventDefault();
           var href = $('#contact_form').attr("action");
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               url: href,
               data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
           });
       });
    });
 });
```

This caused issues on the first/initial load/visit to the contact page and returned the blankCheck function as false.  If all inputs are filled out properly, on page refresh, values remain and the blankCheck test passes with the very same input that failed before refresh.

### ...But!... if I change the blankCheck function to:

```
    function blankCheck(){
       if (emailF.val()!="" && nameF.val()!="" && msgF.val()!="") {
          alert('blankCheck PASS!!!');
          return true;
       } else {
          alert('BLANK FAIL!!!');
          return false;
       };
    });
```

...it *seems* to work as intended.  No need to refresh the page for blankCheck to pass.

**So this has got me wondering: Is it bad practice to store a method in a variable which will be used in an "if" condition?**

Is a method required in a Jquery/JS "if" condition of this nature, or is it ok to use a variable with a stored method inside an "if" condition instead (like the first example `if (nameStr != "" && emailStr != "" && msgStr != "")`) ?

My intuition tells me that there is a problem with my scope (variables, function calls, etc) in the above jquery, but I am still a beginner so take that with a grain of salt.

Does anyone have a good explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: You are not storing a method. You are not checking the "method return value" each time you check for the variable. You are storing the value at that very moment, and will be always the same value although the method returns a different value.

Comment: Thanks Jorge.  So if one is to use a method in a script use it only where/when needed or call a function that includes the method when the resulting value is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store a value before you use it, if it changes before you test it.

Move these to INSIDE the test as you did in example 2. That is how to do it

```
var emailStr = emailF.val();
var nameStr = nameF.val();
var msgStr = msgF.val();
```

Oh, and NEVER call ANYTHING submit in a form
If you ever want to submit the form using script, then form.submit will overwritten by that name or ID

You immediately need to rename your button and use the FORM ID to attach the submit event:

```
  $('#contact_form').on('submit',function(e){
```

using

```
<form id="contact_form">
...
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The second example is what I am currently using in my script.  I just wanted to know what the difference is between the two attempts.  To a new guy, these *seem* to be the same... So you are saying I should rename the id I have for my submit button/input?

Comment: 1. remove the ID, it is not needed. 2. Change the form NAME to ID and use the form ID to add the evnt listener to the submit event

Comment: Your first example is simply storing the values when the page loads and never looks at the changed field values again

Comment: Very nice, and thank you... this makes sense why after adding valid input, the blankCheck fails until page refresh.  The first instance of loading the page reads blank fields, hence the failed blank field test.